# Pushdown predicate between two date ranges if partitioned on the basis of year/month/day

Tags: sql, pyspark, etl, aws-glue, predicate

The following code snippet queries the records from Glue catalog partitioned on S3 as year/month/day:

```
query = f"""(year BETWEEN '{start.year}' AND '{end.year}') AND (month BETWEEN '{start.month}' AND '{end.month}') AND (day BETWEEN '{start.day}' AND '{end.day}')"""
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog( \
    database=database, \
    table_name = "some_glue_catalog_table", \
    push_down_predicate = query) \
    .toDF()
```

But it is challenging to select the data (or predicate) on behalf of year/month/day individually in SQL style. If we opt for the above approach, it will not cover all the days or sometimes months as well. Could somebody please guide further on how we can pass pushdown predicate appropriately?

Thanks.

Comment: one option is to create a string that represents the year, month, day and compare with that, e.g. format_string("%04d%02d%02", year, month, day) between '20220101' and '20230331' (untested)

Comment: Throwing error `d != org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String` with %d, hence I converted all with %s. But still not resulting anything! Just a blank dataframe.